# Multiple columns in 'on' clause

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, conditional-operator

I would like to use the following MySQL statement but I'm not very sure if it is correct:

```
 Delete c 
 From tmp_customers c Inner Join salary s ON 
                    c.id = s.user_id And c.level = s.level
```

to remove from the tmp_customers table all customers with correct defined salary (recore with the correct customer level) and analyze the remaining one.

The statement execution **doesn't give error** but I'm not sure the statement realizes the purpose.

Can I use multiple conditions in the 'on' condition?

Comment: Add the error meassage? multiple condition sould be allowed.

Comment: you can replace `delete c` to `select *` and check the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your query is **correct** and **should work**. Rewritten as:

```
DELETE c 
FROM tmp_customers c
INNER JOIN salary s on (c.id = s.user_id AND c.level = s.level)

-- OR --
-- used a where clause below instead of on --
-- just to show it can also work without on using where --

DELETE c 
FROM tmp_customers c
INNER JOIN salary s
WHERE (c.id = s.user_id AND c.level = s.level)
```

**Answer:** Yes you can use multiple conditions in the **`on`** condition.

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: Added an alternative and answered the exact question I guess.

Comment: "alternative" --- that's why I asked. Spent 2 minutes and couldn't find any difference. So, what exactly have you changed in the original query? Just formatting?

Comment: Answered this - `Can I use multiple conditions in the 'on' condition?`

Comment: that's right. And what have you changed in the original query (it's the 3rd time I'm asking, ohhhh)? I see you provided 2 more queries. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Since the OP has specifically stressed on `on clause` so thought also to add it with `where` also, since generally `delete` query is always expected with a `where`

Comment: oh, that's what I missed. You probably could add an explicit note for someone as blind as me :-D

Comment: @zerkms Note added. :D

Comment: great! this saves 30% of code to check for the second condition ;)